# How can I encode properly pandas to excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a line of code that saves to `xlsx` file but doesn't `encode` properly. I need specifically `ISO-8859-1` format for my `xlsx` file. Here is my code:

```py
export_csv = df.to_csv (r'./test.cvs', index = None, sep=";", header=True, encoding="ISO-8859-1")
export_xls = df.to_excel(r'./test.xlsx', index=None, header=True, encoding='ISO-8859-1')
```

This works for `.csv` file but not for excel file for some reason.

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter

writer = ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\export_xls.xlsx', index = False, sep=";", header=True, encoding="ISO-8859-1")
df.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
```

The file path is a random example.